# Oracle JSON fieldname with special char

Tags: json, oracle

Using an Oracle stored procedure, I'm trying to parse out a list of returned JSON which works fine.

```
JSON_TABLE(lv_clob,'$[*]'
```

The only problem I'm having is this one field name `"access_No_(e.g._abc123)"` that has `(` in the name itself. I'm assuming it's a special character issue because I get an Oracle JSON error because of it.

Is there a way to read that column or convert it to something else? I need the value "YYr11".

Example JSON:

```
{"first_name": "Jon",
"last_name": "Doe",
"street_address": null,
"city": testingcity,
"state": md,
"zip": 11234,
"access_No_(e.g._abc123)": "YYr11",
"allocation": null,
"title": null,
"title_label": null
}
```

My line of code:

```
access_id           VARCHAR2(100)  PATH '$.access_No_(e.g._abc123)'
```

Comment: What error are you getting? It would be helpful to show your whole query, rather than isolating that one line for `access_id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enclose the field name in double-quotes within the `columns` clause:

```
access_id           VARCHAR2(100)  PATH '$."access_No_(e.g._abc123)"'
```

Then the periods (and possibly parentheses) within the field name aren't treated as delimiters.

Quick demo:

```
select * from
JSON_TABLE('{"first_name": "Jon",
"last_name": "Doe",
"street_address": null,
"city": "testingcity",
"state": "md",
"zip": 11234,
"access_No_(e.g._abc123)": "YYr11",
"allocation": null,
"title": null,
"title_label": null
}' format json, '$'
columns
  access_id           VARCHAR2(100)  PATH '$."access_No_(e.g._abc123)"'
);

ACCESS_ID
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
YYr11
```